# How to update apollo cache

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I am wondering why it's very hard to update a data inside of apollo client cache, comparing to similar libraries like react-query it's too complicated

For example, When I have a query with pagination (offset and limit) and get an array of items, When I perform a mutation on one item , and from the server response, I get updated item, how can I replace that cached item?

I found using `updateQuery` required `variables` which means, to updated an item of array, I need to have offset and limit variables. But I don't want to make my code over complicated. I want to replace `item` in the cache

using `cache.modify` is not obvious as well, as it requires `fields` function but I want to easily update all fields

`writeFragment` needs to define Fragment and it's hard as well

Answer (score 1):

> For example, When I have a query with pagination (offset and limit) and get an array of items, When I perform a mutation on one item , and from the server response, I get updated item, how can I replace that cached item?

If you get an updated item in your server response, and both your cache entry as well as the updated response contain an `id` field (or you configured `idFields` in a `typePolicy`), it will be automatically updated and you don't have to write an additional line of code.

In most cases, you won't have to specify any update logic at all, as the Apollo Client cache is normalized.

Comment: Caching is why you should *always* return an id with every object at every level of your query.

Comment: The server returns id, actually I use a same Fragment for both list query and mutation response and both have id field. But the cached value remains stale. I habe tried different cache policy as well.

Comment: How can I trigger updating an element manually? When I have id? And how can I read an element from cache by id

Comment: Reading with `useFragment` or `readFragment` - writing with `writeFragment`.